# How do you find the namespace/module name programmatically in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

How do I find the name of the namespace or module 'Foo' in the filter below?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def get_module_name
    @module_name = ???
  end
end


class Foo::BarController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_module_name
end
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

None of these solutions consider a constant with multiple parent modules.  For instance:

```
A::B::C
```

As of Rails 3.2.x you can simply:

```
"A::B::C".deconstantize #=> "A::B"
```

As of Rails 3.1.x you can:

```
constant_name = "A::B::C"
constant_name.gsub( "::#{constant_name.demodulize}", '' )
```

This is because #demodulize is the opposite of #deconstantize:

```
"A::B::C".demodulize #=> "C"
```

If you really need to do this manually, try this:

```
constant_name = "A::B::C"
constant_name.split( '::' )[0,constant_name.split( '::' ).length-1]
```

Comment: This question was written before Rails 3, and modules weren't really supported.  Updated accepted answer to reflect more current versions!

Comment: demodulize was the key answer

Answer (score 34):

For the simple case, You can use :

```
self.class.parent
```

Comment: Is that available only in recent Rubies ? Can't believe there are so many answers with "dark magic" and none referenced this method until 2015

Comment: Can't find it in the doc... I can't even reproduce :) I prefere this answer now : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778816/how-do-i-get-the-parents-class-name-in-ruby : class C;end; C.new.class.superclass -> Object

Comment: I think my solution worked because of rails : https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/Module#parent-instance_method

Answer (score 22):

This should do it:

```
  def get_module_name
    @module_name = self.class.to_s.split("::").first
  end
```

Comment: or u can also use **self.class.name.demodulize** for that purpose.

Comment: no you can't, actually demodulize does return class name without namespaces

Comment: As Jason Harrelson pointed out, this does not take into consideration multiple parent modules.

Answer (score 21):

#### For Rails 6.1

`self.class.module_parent`

---

Hettomei answer works fine up to Rails 6.0

> DEPRECATION WARNING: `Module#parent` has been renamed to `module_parent`. `parent` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1.

Comment: `module_parent` has been around since Rails 6.0

Comment: This is the type of clean approach I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This would work if the controller did have a module name, but would return the controller name if it did not.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def get_module_name
    @module_name = self.class.name.split("::").first
  end
end
```

However, if we change this up a bit to:

```
class ApplicatioNController < ActionController::Base
  def get_module_name
    my_class_name = self.class.name
    if my_class_name.index("::").nil? then
      @module_name = nil
    else
      @module_name = my_class_name.split("::").first
    end
  end
end
```

You can determine if the class has a module name or not and return something else other than the class name that you can test for.

Answer (score 3):

No one has mentioned using `rpartition`?

```
const_name = 'A::B::C'
namespace, _sep, module_name = const_name.rpartition('::')
# or if you just need the namespace
namespace = const_name.rpartition('::').first
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I just came across the need to have separate navigation depending on the namespace of the controller. The solution I came up with was this in my application layout:

```
<%= render "#{controller.class.name[/^(\w*)::\w*$/, 1].try(:downcase)}/nav" %>
```

Which looks a bit complicated but basically does the following - it takes the controller class name, which would be for example "People" for a non-namespaced controller, and "Admin::Users" for a namespaced one. Using the [] string method with a regular expression that returns anything before two colons, or nil if there's nothing. It then changes that to lower case (the "try" is there in case there is no namespace and nil is returned). This then leaves us with either the namespace or nil. Then it simply renders the partial with or without the namespace, for example no namespace:

```
app/views/_nav.html.erb
```

or in the admin namespace:

```
app/views/admin/_nav.html.erb
```

Of course these partials have to exist for each namespace otherwise an error occurs. Now the navigation for each namespace will appear for every controller without having to change any controller or view.

Answer (score 2):

`my_class.name.underscore.split('/').slice(0..-2)`

or

`my_class.name.split('::').slice(0..-2)`

Answer (score 2):

With many sub-modules:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def namespace
    controller.class.name.gsub(/(::)?\w+Controller$/, '')
  end
end
```

Example: `Foo::Bar::BazController` => `Foo::Bar`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a *cleaner* way, and I've seen this somewhere else

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def get_module_name
    @module_name = self.class.name.split("::").first
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `gsub` instead of `split`. It's more effective that `split` given that you don't need any other module name.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def get_module_name
    @module_name = self.class.to_s.gsub(/::.*/, '')
  end
end
```