# How to check if a class or module is namespaced?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, namespaces

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know if it is possible to check whether a class or module is namespaced. That  is, I would like to run something like the following

```
ANamespaceName::AnotherNamespaceName::AClassName.is_namespaced?
#=> true
ANamespaceName::AClassName.is_namespaced?
#=> true
AClassName.is_namespaced?
#=> false
```

In the above code the issue is related to stating / implementing the `is_namespaced?` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working from "[How do you find the namespace/module name programatically in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133357/how-do-you-find-the-namespace-module-name-programatically-in-ruby-on-rails)" you can use the presence of `::` in the class name to test if there is an associated module.

```
def self.is_namespaced?
    self.name.include? "::"
end
```