# How to tell if an object has a parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just wondering if there is an easy way around this.

I know you can find the parent directly with `@object.parent`
. However I'm puzzled if there is such thing as `@object.parent.exists?`

In my case, `@object` can be any Model. I want to put a condition so that

```
if @object.parent.exists?
    ... do something ...
else
    ... do something else ...
end
```

It could be the case that `@object.other_parent` exists, since my `@object` can be anything.

Comment: You mean you want to see if an `@object` from *any* model has *any* assigned `belongs_to` association?

Comment: Wops (edit). I want to see if an @object belongs_to Parent model or not.
For example: `@object.parent1.exists? =>> false`
                      `@object.parent2.exists? =>> true`

Comment: How are `parent1` and `parent2` defined? Can you post your association definitions from the model? `has_many`, `belongs_to`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go about it is apparently like so:

`@object.attributes.has_key? "parent_id"`

which will return true if a parent of the name "parent" exists, or false if it doesn't

Comment: This is better expressed as `@object.parent_id.present?`, or simply  `@object.parent_id`, which returns nil if `parent_id` is missing. However, this only checks the attribute (ie. the value in the `parent_id` column), and *not* the actual association. Your database might have a parent_id value that refers to a nonexistent row, which will not be detected. `@object.parent` will find the associated parent, if one exists.

Comment: @object.parent_id will return undefined if the @object doesn't have that parent. i.e.: @object.mom exists (will return nil or not) and @object.dad is undefined ( will render error if you try to call it like that ). I haven't tried with .present in this case, but I think calling .present on `undefined` will still fail...

Comment: Uhh, one of us doesn't understand what you are doing, and I hope it's not me. `@object.parent_id` is an attribute on a Rails model, correct? If so, it returns `nil` if the database value is `NULL`. Where are you getting `@object.mom` and `@object.dad`? Are those also columns? Are they methods defined in the model? btw `.present?` is a Rails method that is the inverse of `.blank?`, so `nil.present?` returns `false`.

Comment: `@object.parent_id` may or may not be an attribute of the model. In fact, `@object` may be a variety of different models. What I'm interested in, is if the model of the `@object` (ie. `object.class`) is a child of say... "Mom". many Models in my app can be children of Mom, and some are not. (some models have attribute mom_id, and some don't). What I wanted to find out, was if the `@object` had a Mom parent or not. (ie. if @object.mom_id is not undefined, it is)

Comment: OK, clearly I lack enough information to make a useful comment. Feel free to as another question if you feel it necessary, otherwise, good luck.

Comment: actually I am not sure if this is the right answer. I think when you do `@object.attributes.has_key? "parent_id"` you are only checking if there is a relationship between a child and their parent. You are not checking if a specific child is associated with another specific parent. Your piece of code should return true all the time provided you have done the proper migrations.. I am wanting to do the same in my app and I will get back on this once I find out. (I want to know if parent with id 222 is the parent of child with id 111 .. or whatever ids)

Comment: Its been a while since I posted that question.. I solved it with what I proposed above... Its not ideal, but worked for me... Still, I had to know which 'parent's the child could possibly belong to (the possibilities could be many).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have `parent` set up as an ActiveRecord relation, you should be able to call:

```
if @object.parent
```

However, if you're referring to the [realms of Superclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778816/how-do-i-get-the-parents-class-name-in-ruby), whereby your object inherits from a "parent" class, you'll have to use something like the `superclass` property:

```
if @object.superclass
```

I don't believe `exists` will be applicable here. The `parent` object will either exist or not. If it doesn't exist, you won't be able to call it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the parent is defined by a `parent_id` on the object model. you could just call `.nil?` on that attribute to check if it exists

Comment: you better try it, verify and then answer. Guessing is not answering