# Rails: How to redirect to a specific controller (index) depending on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails application that can generate "roles" for actors in movies; the idea is that if a user looks at a movie detail page, they can click "add role", and the same if they look at an actor detail page.
Once the role is generated, I would like to redirect back to where they came from - the movie detail page or the actor detail page... so in the controller's "create" and "update" method, the redirect_to should either be movie_path(id) or actor_path(id). How do I keep the "origin" persistent, i. e. how do I remember whether the user came from movie detail or from actor detail (and the id, respectively)?

Comment: You can use `request.referer` to know where the `add role` action is being triggered and store it in the session object or add it as a hidden field in your form. Then when the for is submitted you can check the session or that hidden field in your params to know where to go back to

Comment: Good idea, quite straightforward. Will probably try this before I dare the more complex solution below! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would setup separate nested routes and just use inheritance, mixins and partials to avoid duplication:

```
resources :movies do
  resources :roles, module: :movies, only: :create
end

resources :actors do
  resources :roles, module: :actors, only: :create
end
```

```
class RolesController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :set_parent

  def create
    @role = @parent.roles.create(role_params)
    if @role.save 
      redirect_to @parent
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private 

  # guesses the name based on the module nesting
  # assumes that you are using Rails 6+ 
  # see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133357/how-do-you-find-the-namespace-module-name-programmatically-in-ruby-on-rails
  def parent_class
    module_parent.name.singularize.constantize
  end

  def set_parent
    parent_class.find(param_key)
  end

  def param_key
    parent_class.model_name.param_key + "_id"
  end

  def role_params
    params.require(:role)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
  end
end
```

```
module Movies
  class RolesController < ::RolesController
  end
end
```

```
module Actors
  class RolesController < ::RolesController
  end
end
```

```
# roles/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: [parent, role]) do |form| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wow, cool, I just realize how MUCH there is in Rails.. and how much I still csn learn! Thanks!