# Reusing model in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently in the process of adding comments to one of my models `MaintenanceRequest` and wondering how I should go about this.

I have a model `Offer` which already has comments built and it is set up with ActionCable as follows

```rb
# models/comment.rb

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :offer
end
```

```rb
# channels/comment_channel.rb

class CommentChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    offer = Offer.find params[:offer]
    stream_for offer
  end
end
```

and the comment controller looks as

```rb
# controllers/comments_controller.rb

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :is_valid_offer

  def create
    offer = Offer.find(comment_params[:offer_id])

    if comment_params[:content].blank?
      # return redirect_to request.referrer, alert: 'Comment cannot be empty.'
      return render json: {success: false}
    end

    if offer.user_id != current_user.id && offer.landlord_id != current_user.id
      return render json: {success: false}
    end

    @comment = Comment.new(
      user_id: current_user.id,
      offer_id: offer.id,
      content: comment_params[:content],
    )

    if @comment.save
      # redirect_to request.referrer, notice: 'Comment sent.'
      CommentChannel.broadcast_to offer, message: render_comment(@comment)
      render json: {success: true}
    else
      redirect_to request.referrer, alert: "Couldn't send comment."
      render json: {success: true}
    end
  end
end
```

My question is that is there a way I could use the same model for comments belonging to `MaintenanceRequest` or should I just create new model and controller for there comments? It would seem that this would get quite messy if I tried to reuse the current comment model. What would be the "best practice" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a resuable assocation you want to use a polymorphic assocation:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, 
    polymorphic: true

  validates :content, 
    presence: true
end
```

Instead of using a single column holding an integer pointing to a fixed table this "cheats" the relation database model by using a one column for the other tables primary key and storing the class name of the entitity in a string column (in this example called `commentable_type`).

You can create the needed columns by passing the polymorphic option when generating the migration (or model):

```
rails g migration add_commentable_to_comments commentable:belongs_to{polymorphic}
```

However that controller action is a bit of train wreck. It should look more like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_offer
  before_action :authorize_user

  def create
    @comment = @offer.comments.new(comment_params) do |c|
      c.user = current_user
    end

    if @comment.save
      # redirect_to request.referrer, notice: 'Comment sent.'
      CommentChannel.broadcast_to offer, message: render_comment(@comment)
      # rendering json here is actually just stupid. Just use a HTTP status code 
      # as a response if you're not actually returning the rendered entity.
      render json: { success: true }, 
        status: :created,
        location: @comment
    else
      # either return JSON which is actually useful or just a status code
      render json: { success: false }, 
        status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def set_offer
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:offer_id])
  end

  # this should be extracted to an authorization layer such as Pundit
  def authorize_offer
    if @offer.user_id != current_user.id && @offer.landlord_id != current_user.id 
      render json: { success: false },
        status: :unauthorized
    end
  end
end
```

There are two way to resuse this controller for different types of "commentables". You can either check for the presence of the `offer_id` or `maintenance_request_id` in a single controller and use that to deduce the class or you can use inheritance to destribute the responsibilities better:

```
# routes.rb

resources :offers do
  resources :comments, 
    only: :create,
    module: :offers
end

resources :maintainence_requests do
  resources :comments, 
    only: :create,
    module: :maintainence_requests
end
```

```
class CommentsController
  before_action :set_commentable, only: [:new, :create, :index]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  attr_reader :commentable

  def create
    @comment = commentable.comments.new(comment_params) do |c|
      c.user = current_user
    end
    if @comment.save
      # simple extendability feature that lets you "tap into" the flow 
      # by passing a block when calling super in subclasses
      yield @comment if block_given?
      render json: @comment,
             status: :created
    else
      render json: { errors: @comment.errors.full_messages },
             status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  
  private

  # Uses simple heuristics based on module nesting to guess the name of the model
  # that is being commented upon. Overide if needed.
  # @example Foos::BarsController -> Foo
  def commentable_class
    @commentable_class ||= self.class.module_parent.name.singularize.constantize
  end 

  def commentable_param_key
    commentable_class.model_name.param_key
  end

  def set_commentable
    @commentable = commentable_class.find("#{commentable_param_key}_id")
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment)
          .permit(:content)
  end
end
```

```
module Offers
  class CommentsController < ::CommentsController
    # POST /offers/:offer_id/comments
    def create
      # block is called after a comment is succesfully saved but before 
      # the response is set
      super do |comment|
        CommentChannel.broadcast_to comment.offer, 
          message: render_comment(comment) 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
module MaintainenceRequests
  class CommentsController < ::CommentsController
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for refactoring the controller methods... Your suggestion seems to be to use single model for the comments instead of creating another one?

Comment: It depends a bit on the use case and if a "offer comment" and a "maintainence request comment" are actually the same thing (which can be hard to know initially) as well as aspects like if you expect to need to query it as a homogenious collection.

Comment: In a sense they are the same thing. Both are just text fields, but related to different models.

Comment: The con of using polymorphic assocations is that its a hack to get around the object relational impedence missmatch and the relations can only really be resolved by the application as well as the lack of foreign key constraints to maintain referential integrity on the DB level.

Comment: I suppose the route for maintenance_requests should have `module: :maintenance_requests`? Also The module `MaintainenceRequests` is it empty or copy from the Offers module?

Comment: @Daniel yeah that was a copy paste mistake. The MaintenanceRequests module is just a plain old module. You could also nest it in the model class but that wasn't done historically due to a now fixed bug in Ruby.

Comment: Some odd error popping up with the comments controller. `NoMethodError (undefined method 'singularize' for Object:Class):` It would seem that `module_parent` isn't a string?

Comment: @Daniel ah yes, should have warned you that the code is untested an probably contains quite a few small bugs. In this case it should be`module_parent.name.singularize`

Comment: I see. Thanks anyway. I'll try to use this as a baseline and fix what ever bugs might come up. Only thing I'm concerned about is that how will ActionCable work with this. It seems that you're broadcasting from the module and I'm not sure if it's some rails magic or what that makes it work but we'll see.

Comment: Is there some specific location for the Offer module to be in for this to work? The commentable_class method still returns Object since `self.class.module_parent.name` returns "Object" and calling constantize will just convert this string back to Object. And this in turn will lead to an error in commentable_param_key method since NoMethodError (undefined method `model_name' for Object:Class

Comment: Someting is off there. You can always just implement `def commentable_class; Offer; end` in `Offers::OffersController` and skip the magic. It was based off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133357/how-do-you-find-the-namespace-module-name-programmatically-in-ruby-on-rails and my VM is broken right now so cant test it.

Comment: One workaround is the good old way `self.class.name.split('::').first`. I'm not sure why `module_parent` doesn't work in this case.